# How to find a Map in a Map List?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my code I have a list of Maps, something like this:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> list;

list = [
   {"name" : "name1", "date" : '01/08/2020'}
   {"name" : "name2", "date" : '01/08/2020'}
];
```

*obs: instead of String I'm using DateTime object to set the value of date key*

but when I try to delete some item in list using

```
list.removeAt(list.indexOf({"name" : "name1", "date" : '01/08/2020'}));
```

the function `indexOf()` return -1.

How can i find a item to delete or modify in this list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could so something like this using `removeWhere`

```
list.removeWhere((m) => m["name"] == "name1" && m["date"] == "01/08/2020");
```